# How to fix Checkmarx XSS vulnerability for getInputStream

Tags: java, xss, secure-coding, checkmarx

This piece of code is not passed by Checkmarx.  It complains that the getInputStream() is not sanitized and/or validated. Any idea how to fix it?

```java
protected HttpRequest buildProxyRequestWithEntity(String method, String proxyRequestUrl,
                                                  HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
    HttpEntityEnclosingRequest proxyRequest = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest(method, proxyRequestUrl);
    proxyRequest
          .setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(servletRequest.getInputStream(), getContentLength(servletRequest)));

    return proxyRequest;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkmarx - How to validate and sanitize HttpServletRequest .getInputStream to pass checkmarx scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64152836/checkmarx-how-to-validate-and-sanitize-httpservletrequest-getinputstream-to-p)

Comment: No because they're not using servletRequest.